# How do I hide angular material FormGroup from the dom until data is loaded from the background?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have simple webpage, containing a form group with few controls in it. Inside my ngOnInit method, I am making a get request to load some data from the sever. Until this data is loaded, I want to hide the form, and display it only after the data is loaded. 
Here is my `.component.ts` file:

```
public formGroup = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
    ]),
    lastName: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
    ]),
  });
```

Here is my `ngOnInit()` method:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.pipe(mergeMap(params => {
      this.param1 = params['param'];
      this.hideForm();   //I want to implement this method
      return this.service.getInfo(this.param1);
    })).subscribe(data => {
//this is the success case, i.e. I have loaded the data and obv I want to show the form
      this.formGroup.controls['firstName'].setValue(data.firstName);
      this.formGroup.controls['lastName'].setValue(data.lastName);
    }, err => {
      //in the error case the form should stay hidden
    });
  }
```

Part of my `component.html` file:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="handleSubmit()">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="firstName" required>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Surname" formControlName="lastName" required>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

I have read that I can remove/add controls from the form, but this seem unnecessary for my, to constantly adding and removing components instead of hiding them. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the data received to a variable and add an `*ngIf` to the form checking if that variable has a value.

component.ts

```
    public formData;
    ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.pipe(mergeMap(params => {
      this.param1 = params['param'];
      this.hideForm();   //I want to implement this method
      return this.service.getInfo(this.param1);
    })).subscribe(data => {
      this.formData = data;
      this.formGroup.controls['title'].setValue(data.title);
      this.formGroup.controls['firstName'].setValue(data.firstName);
      this.formGroup.controls['lastName'].setValue(data.lastName);
      this.formGroup.controls['email'].setValue(data.email);
    }, err => {
      //in the error case the form should stay hidden
    });
  }
```

template

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="handleSubmit()" *ngIf="formData">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Title" formControlName="title" required>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="firstName" required>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Surname" formControlName="lastName" required>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="Email" placeholder="Enter your email" formControlName="email" required>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an `isLoaded` flag on the component, and an `*ngIf` to hide/show the form.

Eg:

```
<form *ngIf="isLoaded" [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="handleSubmit()">
```

(and setting isLoaded to true/false as appropriate in your ngInit function)

Comment: This does not work for me, because the `ngOnInit` method is called only once, and hence the form is never shown (because I have declared `loadedData: boolean;`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ngIf** that will evaluate to true only once the data is available on the **form** element or its wrapper.

Alternatively, you can use the built-in capabilities of the Router to navigate to the given route only when certain data is available, e.g.:

[Wait for Data Before Rendering Views](https://shermandigital.com/blog/wait-for-data-before-rendering-views-in-angular-2/)

[The right way to prefetch data for your angular components](https://codeburst.io/the-right-way-to-prefetch-data-for-your-angular-components-pages-1e5cce099cee)

[Load All Data Before Loading The Component View In Angular 6](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/load-all-data-before-loading-the-component-view-in-angular-6/)

... etc.